# Flappy bird на pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Пытаюсь сделать Flappy Bird pygame. Это моя первая игра. Все было хорошо, игра работала, пока я не захотел добавить окна "Start Screen". Сделал 3 функции , каждая отвечает за отдельное окно: title_screen,  play_level, game_over_screen.
Меняю экраны я с помощью класса GameState:

```
    while True:

        if game_state == GameState.TITLE:
            game_state = title_screen(screen, game_state)

        if game_state == GameState.NEWGAME:
            game_state = play_level(screen, game_state, score)

        if game_state == GameState.LOST:
            print('LOST')
            game_state = game_over_screen(screen, game_state)

        if game_state == GameState.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            return
```

C окна title_screen обе кнопки работают (кнопка начала игры и выхода). Но в окне play_level не работает логика окончания игры (пересечение птицы с трубой и падение птицы ниже пола, не работает счетчик очков (накручивается при пролете между трубами ))

```
        if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() >= 700:
            game_state = game_state.LOST
```

```
        if game_state == GameState.NEWGAME:

            # Pipes logic
            rem = []

            add_pipe = False
            for pipe in pipes:
                if pipe.collide(bird, screen):
                    game_state = game_state.LOST
                if pipe.x + pipe.PIPE_TOP.get_width() < 0:
                    rem.append(pipe)

                if not pipe.passed and pipe.x < bird.x:
                    pipe.passed = True
                    add_pipe = True
                pipe.move()
            if add_pipe:
                score += 1

                pipes.append(Pipe(700))

            for r in rem:
                pipes.remove(r)
                pipe.move()
```

Может стоит как то по другому написать логику смены экранов, подскажите пожалуйста!

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import RenderUpdates
import os
from enum import Enum
from Pipe import Pipe
from Bird import Bird
from Base import Base
from UIElement import UIElement


pygame.font.init()
pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36)

BLUE = (106, 159, 181)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800

BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bg.png")))


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    game_state = GameState.TITLE
    score = 0

    while True:

        if game_state == GameState.TITLE:
            game_state = title_screen(screen, game_state)

        if game_state == GameState.NEWGAME:
            game_state = play_level(screen, game_state, score)

        if game_state == GameState.LOST:
            print('LOST')
            game_state = game_over_screen(screen, game_state)

        if game_state == GameState.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            return


def title_screen(screen, game_state):
    start_btn = UIElement(
        center_position=(WIN_WIDTH/2, 400),
        font_size=30,
        bg_rgb=BLUE,
        text_rgb=WHITE,
        text="Start",
        action=GameState.NEWGAME,
    )
    quit_btn = UIElement(
        center_position=(WIN_WIDTH/2, 480),
        font_size=30,
        bg_rgb=BLUE,
        text_rgb=WHITE,
        text="Quit",
        action=GameState.QUIT,
    )

    buttons = RenderUpdates(start_btn, quit_btn)

    return screens_loop(screen, buttons, game_state)


def game_over_screen(screen, game_state):
    start_btn = UIElement(
        center_position=(WIN_WIDTH/2, 400),
        font_size=30,
        bg_rgb=BLUE,
        text_rgb=WHITE,
        text="Start New Game",
        action=GameState.NEWGAME,
    )
    quit_btn = UIElement(
        center_position=(WIN_WIDTH/2, 480),
        font_size=30,
        bg_rgb=BLUE,
        text_rgb=WHITE,
        text="Quit",
        action=GameState.QUIT,
    )

    # f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
    # lost = f1.render('YOU LOST ', True, (100, 100, 0))
    # screen.blit(lost, (10, 10))

    buttons = RenderUpdates(start_btn, quit_btn)

    return screens_loop(screen, buttons, game_state)


def play_level(screen, game_state, score):
    return_btn = UIElement(
        center_position=(80, WIN_HEIGHT-10),
        font_size=15,
        bg_rgb=BLUE,
        text_rgb=WHITE,
        text="To main menu",
        action=GameState.TITLE,
    )

    bird = Bird(130, 320)
    base = Base(730)
    pipes = [Pipe(700)]

    f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
    score_draw = f1.render('Score ' + str(score), True, (100, 100, 0))
    buttons = RenderUpdates(return_btn)

    return game_loop(screen, buttons, game_state, score_draw, pipes, score, bird, base)


def game_loop(screen, buttons, game_state, score_draw, pipes, score, bird, base):
    """ Handles game loop until an action is return by a button in the
        buttons sprite renderer.
    """

    while True:
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        clock.tick(30)
        mouse_up = False

        # Catching events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_TAB:
                    bird.jump()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
                mouse_up = True

        if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() >= 700:
            game_state = game_state.LOST

        if game_state == GameState.NEWGAME:

            # Pipes logic
            rem = []

            add_pipe = False
            for pipe in pipes:
                if pipe.collide(bird, screen):
                    game_state = game_state.LOST
                if pipe.x + pipe.PIPE_TOP.get_width() < 0:
                    rem.append(pipe)

                if not pipe.passed and pipe.x < bird.x:
                    pipe.passed = True
                    add_pipe = True
                pipe.move()
            if add_pipe:
                score += 1

                pipes.append(Pipe(700))

            for r in rem:
                pipes.remove(r)
                pipe.move()

            # Draw part

            screen.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))
            for pipe in pipes:
                pipe.draw(screen)
            screen.blit(score_draw, (10, 10))
            base.draw(screen)
            bird.draw(screen)
            base.move()
            bird.move()

        for button in buttons:
            ui_action = button.update(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), mouse_up)
            if ui_action is not None:
                return ui_action

        buttons.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()


def screens_loop(screen, buttons, game_state):
    """ Handles game loop until an action is return by a button in the
        buttons sprite renderer.
    """
    while True:
        mouse_up = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
                mouse_up = True
        screen.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))

        if game_state == GameState.TITLE:
            screen.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))

        if game_state == GameState.LOST:
            print('LOST screen')
            screen.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))

        for button in buttons:
            ui_action = button.update(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), mouse_up)
            if ui_action is not None:
                return ui_action

        buttons.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()


class GameState(Enum):
    QUIT = -1
    TITLE = 0
    NEWGAME = 1
    NEXT_LEVEL = 2
    LOST = 3


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено!

функция main не получала изменение значения класса game_state, решил просто добавив сточку return game_state.

Было:

```
if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() >= 700:
            game_state = game_state.LOST
```

Стало:

```
if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() >= 700:
            game_state = game_state.LOST
            return game_state
```

Было:

```
  for pipe in pipes:
                if pipe.collide(bird, screen):
                    game_state = game_state.LOST
```

Стало:

```
  for pipe in pipes:
                if pipe.collide(bird, screen):
                    game_state = game_state.LOST
                    return game_state
```